# SQL query to count number of days with reappearing entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with access controll log entries:

```
time : datetime (this is the access timestamp)
src: text (this is the userid)
```

I want to get a list out of it that shows how many users from the current day had already access on how many days during the past 7 days. The result should look like this:

```
number of days with access |  count
1                          |   30
2                          |   54
3                          |   123
4                          |   843
5                          |   3490
6                          |   71
7                          |   23
```

What I have so far:

The query below returns the number of users with log entry on 2015-03-08 that had also an entry on 2015-03-07.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT a.src)
FROM   contacts AS a
       LEFT JOIN contacts AS b
              ON a.src = b.src
WHERE  a.time BETWEEN Cast('2015-03-08 05:00:00' AS DATETIME) AND Cast('2015-03-09 05:00:00' AS DATETIME)
       AND b.time BETWEEN Cast('2015-03-07 05:00:00' AS DATETIME) AND Cast('2015-03-08 05:00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

But I'm stuck with getting the count for each dayby number of days as described above. If there is no 'sql only' solution it would be ok as well to have an (performant) approach using php. Thanks for any help..

Comment: `..AND b.time between..` is going to convert your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why do you need to join b table.

```
SELECT 
  DAY(a.time),
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.src)
FROM   contacts AS a
WHERE  a.time 
   BETWEEN (TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
     AND TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 23:59:59'))
GROUP BY DAY(a.time)
```

Comment: I dont want to count distinct src values per day. I want to know how many of my todays visitors have logged in only today, or today and on 1 other day, or today and on 2 other days and so on